# How to safe game scores per level on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

I have a facebook app defined as game and I want to save the users score, time and rating for each level. Is this possible at all?

I've been reading about saving highscores on Facebook, but couldn't find a good beginners tutorial about this. Does anyone know some good tutorials?

Basicly I want to save the following items:

- Levelname
- levelscore
- levelrating
- leveltime

The idea: Users can choose a level and see their highest score so far per level. If they have a better score after replaying, the new score, time, etc should be saved.

Thank you for you time

Kind regards,
Maurice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm still figuring out the Facebook scores API myself but no, it doesn't look like this is possible. You can only publish a single score, and only the score, for your game. You could give your users an achievement for completing each level, but even then you couldn't store your rating and time.

Really, you only need to use the Facebook score API so that your players can see when their friends have played, and if they got a better score then you did. I'd say just use your own database to keep that stuff.

Comment: Hi, thanks, I agree and already using my own database. The documentation about this and the achievements are very poor. So the scoring I'll do using my own db. How about the achievements. Do you happen to know some tutorials etc how to use this? Thanks